# How to find the next occurring item from current row in a data frame using Spark Windowing?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, windowing

I have the following Dataframe:

```
+------+----------+-------------+--------------------+---------+-----+----------+
|ID    |MEM_ID    | BFS         | SVC_DT             |TYP      |SEQ  |BFS_SEQ   |
+------+----------+----------------------------------+---------+-----+----------+
|105771|29378668  | BRIMONIDINE | 2019-02-04 00:00:00|PD       |1    |1         |
|105772|29378668  | BRIMONIDINE | 2019-04-04 00:00:00|PD       |2    |2         |
|105773|29378668  | BRIMONIDINE | 2019-04-17 00:00:00|RV       |3    |3         |
|105774|29378668  | TIMOLOL     | 2019-04-17 00:00:00|RV       |4    |1         |
|105775|29378668  | BRIMONIDINE | 2019-04-22 00:00:00|PD       |5    |4         |
|105776|29378668  | TIMOLOL     | 2019-04-22 00:00:00|PD       |6    |2         |
+------+----------+----------------------------------+---------+-----+----------+
```

For every row, I have to find the occurrence of next 'PD' Typ at BFS level from the current row and populate its associated ID as a new column named 'NEXT_PD_TYP_ID'

The output I am expecting is:

```
+------+---------+-------------+--------------------+----+-----+---------+---------------+
|ID    |MEM_ID   | BFS         | SVC_DT             |TYP |SEQ  |BFS_SEQ  |NEXT_PD_TYP_ID |
+------+---------+----------------------------------+----+-----+---------+---------------+
|105771|29378668 | BRIMONIDINE | 2019-02-04 00:00:00|PD  |1    |1        |105772         |
|105772|29378668 | BRIMONIDINE | 2019-04-04 00:00:00|PD  |2    |2        |105775         | 
|105773|29378668 | BRIMONIDINE | 2019-04-17 00:00:00|RV  |3    |3        |105775         |
|105774|29378668 | TIMOLOL     | 2019-04-17 00:00:00|RV  |4    |1        |105776         |
|105775|29378668 | BRIMONIDINE | 2019-04-22 00:00:00|PD  |5    |4        |null           | 
|105776|29378668 | TIMOLOL     | 2019-04-22 00:00:00|PD  |6    |2        |null           |
+------+---------+----------------------------------+----+-----+---------+---------------+
```

Need help.

I have tried using the conditional aggregation: max(when), however since it has more than one 'PD' the max is returning only one value for all the rows.

No error messages

Comment: In the expected output, Why is `NEXT_PD_TYP_ID` for second row `10577157138201326548`?  Row with ID 10577157138201326548 has `TYP` = `RV`

Comment: Sorry! My bad while posting the question. Have updated the correct expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps. 
I created a new column with ID's of TYP === PD. I called it TYPPDID.
Then I used Window frame ranging from next row to unbounded following row and got the first not-null TYPPDID
`orderBy("ID")` in the end is only to show records in order.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
("105771", "BRIMONIDINE", "PD"),
("105772", "BRIMONIDINE", "PD"),
("105773", "BRIMONIDINE","RV"),
("105774", "TIMOLOL", "RV"),
("105775", "BRIMONIDINE", "PD"),
("105776", "TIMOLOL", "PD")
).toDF("ID", "BFS", "TYP").withColumn("TYPPDID", when($"TYP" === "PD", $"ID"))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ID: string, BFS: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> df.show
+------+-----------+---+-------+
|    ID|        BFS|TYP|TYPPDID|
+------+-----------+---+-------+
|105771|BRIMONIDINE| PD| 105771|
|105772|BRIMONIDINE| PD| 105772|
|105773|BRIMONIDINE| RV|   null|
|105774|    TIMOLOL| RV|   null|
|105775|BRIMONIDINE| PD| 105775|
|105776|    TIMOLOL| PD| 105776|
+------+-----------+---+-------+


scala> val overColumns = Window.partitionBy("BFS").orderBy("ID").rowsBetween(1, Window.unboundedFollowing)
overColumns: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec@eb923ef


scala> df.withColumn("NEXT_PD_TYP_ID",first("TYPPDID", true).over(overColumns)).orderBy("ID").show(false)
+------+-----------+---+-------+-------+
|ID    |BFS        |TYP|TYPPDID|NEXT_PD_TYP_ID|
+------+-----------+---+-------+-------+
|105771|BRIMONIDINE|PD |105771 |105772 |
|105772|BRIMONIDINE|PD |105772 |105775 |
|105773|BRIMONIDINE|RV |null   |105775 |
|105774|TIMOLOL    |RV |null   |105776 |
|105775|BRIMONIDINE|PD |105775 |null   |
|105776|TIMOLOL    |PD |105776 |null   |
+------+-----------+---+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: unboundedFollowing is since Spark 2.3.0 I will try if I can find a sol in 1.6

Comment: Wondering how to implement the same in Spark 1.6? Spark 1.6 doesn't support Window.unboundedFollowing. I used .rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, Long.MaxValue). However, Spark 1.6 doesn't take first("TYPPDID", true). I see an error stating "Too many arguments for first"

Comment: No, you cannot use Long.MinValue. your frame is from next row ( relative to current row) to last following row.

Comment: In Spark 1.6, since there is no first("TYPPDID", true), I am trying the following: 

df.withColumn("NEXT_PD_TYP_ID", when(col("TYPPDID").isNotNull, first("TYPPDID").over(w2))).orderBy("ID").show(false)

Still, it isn't giving me the correct results